# How to align Components horizontal

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I use ExtJS for a gridview and I now need a search option above the grid. So I created a panel and added the items such as a textbox and two buttons to it. It all works fine except of the layout. I need the textbox and two buttons to be align horizontally instead of vertically. I already tried to inject html elements like styles without any success.

**How can I align components horizontal within a container?**

```
   var formPanel=Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Catalog Search',
        width:300,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        submitOnAction: true,
        activeItem: 1,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'Job Name',
            id:'JobName',
            fieldLabel: 'Job Name',
            allowBlank: false,

           }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            name: 'search',
            fieldLabel: 'Catalog Search',
            text: 'Search',
             html:'style=float:left',
            width:100,

            listeners:{
                click:function(){
                    var searchText=Ext.getCmp('JobName').getValue();
                    store.proxy.extraParams={
                        id: searchText
                    };
                    store.load();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            name: 'clear',
            fieldLabel: 'Clear',
            text: 'Clear',
            width:100,

            listeners:{
                click:function(){
                    Ext.getCmp('JobName').reset();
                     var searchText='';
                    store.proxy.extraParams={
                        id: searchText

                    };
                   store.load();
                }
            }
        }
        ]


    });
    formPanel.render('paging-grid');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a appropriate layout like hbox for such a case.

See this working example (**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/Sj8zM/22/)**)

```
var formPanel=Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Catalog Search',
    width:500,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: 'paging-grid',
    submitOnAction: true,
    layout: 'hbox',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Job Name',
        id:'JobName',
        fieldLabel: 'Job Name',
        allowBlank: false,
        flex: 1
       }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        name: 'search',
        fieldLabel: 'Catalog Search',
        text: 'Search',
        style: 'margin-left: 10px',
        width: 70
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        name: 'clear',
        fieldLabel: 'Clear',
        text: 'Clear',
        style: 'margin-left: 10px',
        width: 70
    }
    ]
});
```

Btw: a button has a `handler` property which is the wrapped `click` event. You can supply a function directly to that method without the need to register yourself to the listener.